# What is the difference between O(N) + O(M) and O(N + M). Is there any?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I'm solving problems for interview practice and I can't seem to figure out the answer to the time and space complexity of the following problem:

> Given two sorted Linked Lists, merge them into a third list in sorted order. Let's assume we are using descending ordering.

One of the answers I came across, which is clearly not the most efficient one, is the following recursive solution:

```
Node mergeLists(Node head1, Node head2) {
    if (head1 == null) {
        return head2;
    } else if (head2 == null) {
        return head1;
    }

    Node newHead = null;
    if(head1.data < head2.data) {
        newHead = head1;
        newHead.next = mergeLists(head1.next, head2);
    } else {
        newHead = head2;
        newHead.next = mergeLists(head1, head2.next);
    }

    return newHead;
}
```

Now, when I was analyzing the complexity of this function, I came across an issue. I wasn't sure if it was `O(M + N)` or `O(M) + O(N)`. I just cannot get an intuitive answer. It seems logical to me that the run-time and space complexities of this function are `O(N) + O(M)` or `O(max(N,M))` since the larger value would drive the asymptotic curve (or the recursive calls and stack frame creations).

To sum up:

In big-Oh notation, **what is the difference between `O(N+M)` and `O(N) + O(M)`?** Is there any? If they differ, I would appreciate if somebody could provide simple examples of both.

Comment: Where are you seeing "O(n)+O(m)"?

Comment: Well, we are checking all nodes of each list no matter what M and N are? Clearly I am not 100% sure which of the two is the answer since I am asking a question here :)
Technically, as I've said above, I think the answer is O(max(N,M)) since the larger value would be the asymptotic bound.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`O(N) + O(M)` means functions that are bounded by `cN + dM` for some `c` and `d`.

`O(N + M)` means functions that are bounded by `e(N + M)` for some `e`.

They are equivalent because:

`cN + dM <= (c + d)(N + M)` for some `c` and `d`.

and

`e(N + M) <= eN + eM` for some `e`.